# Finding the max coordinates of GeoTIF image

Tags: mapbox, geospatial, geotiff

I am working with weather data and experimenting with some new products, and I need to find the coordinates of a GEOTIF image so I can overlay it on a map in Mapbox. I seem to be having trouble finding the coords in decimal format for this particular file:

http://flash.ou.edu/flash_web/ratio_1h/01H.RAT.20180811.101800.tif

(You can alternatively go to http://flash.ou.edu./cgi-bin/tab_ProductMaps.cgi?0 and click on "product selection" on the left, and select 1H QPE FFG ratio, then scroll to the bottom of the page and the link to the TIF is "Download Data" at the very bottom, the data is always changing but the coords are the same).

The actual full geospatial coordinates are not listed on the website, and I have used 2 GIS programs to get the coords but I cannot find them, or the image does not have them attached and it's just a TIF. I am not an expert in this field and I don't know the coords are even in the file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the tif file with QGIS and view the spatial extent in the layer properties/metadata.

```
-130.0000000000000000,20.0000000000000000 : -60.0000000000000000,55.0000000000000000
```

xMin: -130°, yMin: 20° : xMax: -60°, yMax: 55°

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I will get this immediately.